# Por que usar session_cache_limiter()

Tags: php

Eu deveria usar **session_cache_limiter()** ?? por que ??

Valores: nocache, private, private_no_expire ou public.

Comment: Podes dar um contexto à pergunta? É que assim não se percebe em que contexto queres usar isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Cache” é uma forma de armazenar um valor para um consulta futura mais rápida. Com o cache conseguimos otimizar o carregamento dos sites e de suas informações.

Suponhamos que você tenha um site que faça uma consulta em um tabela do banco de dados que possua 3.000.000 registros e essa consulta demore mais de 30 segundos (acredite, isso acontece). Com o cache você pode reduzir esse tempo em alguns segundos, em relação a user ou não isso depende de como você queira que seu sistema se comporte.

Cachear uma informação significa salvá-la em algum lugar (seja em um arquivo ou diretamente na memória RAM do servidor) para depois poder consultar essa informação sem ter que obtê-la da forma mais demorada (no exemplo a cima, com a consulta ao banco de dados).

Quando voce determina um tipo de cache para o sistema significa que;

- nochace: rejeitaria qualquer armazenamento no cache do cliente.
- private: um pouco mais restritivo do que public.
- private_no_expire: Header expirado nunca é enviado para o cliente nesse modo.
- public: permitiria o armazenamento no cache

Você pode consultar mais detalhes e exemplos [na documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-cache-limiter.php)

Fonte: [Thiago belem](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criando-um-sistema-de-cache-no-php/)